# KeyCode of  backtick key

Tags: java, keyevent

I'm trying to type some text into a text field using the Robot class in Java.

The problem I have is, that I can not discover the integer value of the backtick key (to the left of 1 on the keyboard).

I have no idea which one of the VK_ constants in the KeyEvent class it is.

At first I assumed it was 96, but pressing it using the robot gives me `0` (maybe 96 is the numpad zero).

What is the integer keycode for backtick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`VK_BACK_QUOTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_BACK_QUOTE) is the code you want. It has integer value `192`.

Answer (score 1):

If microsoft layout editor is right, VK_OEM_3 . Does it make sense?